# Image Adapter Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android

A little context first: I'm making a gallery as a part of my app,because i found no way of importing multiple pictures in android. For this purpose the code below accesses the camera directory and then puts the images in a GridView via and adapter, but the adapter displays the pictures in a list rather than a grid also a bigger issue is the app wont crashes just about a second after load,but it does display the Xamarin watermark(this build will only work for 24 hours message).

The problems i need your help with are,why my app wont run in a phone and how come it runs in emulator and second why does it display in list rather than a  grid?

I have write external storage and read external storage permissions selected.

I'll b really grateful if anyone would help me out.

My Main File

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    List<string> URIs=new List<string> ();// un parsed URIs

    List<ImageView> IMGs;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        IMGs = new List<ImageView> ();
        GetImageFileNames ();
        MakeImageViews ();

        Toast.MakeText (this,"this is sparta",ToastLength.Short).Show ();

        GridView gridView = FindViewById<GridView> (Resource.Id.gridView1);

        PicAdapter PA=  new PicAdapter (this,IMGs);

        gridView.Adapter = PA; 

        }

    void MakeImageViews ()
    {   
        foreach (string uri in URIs) 
        {
            Android.Net.Uri _uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams (85, 85);
            imageView.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
            imageView.SetPadding (8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.SetImageURI (_uri);
            IMGs.Add (imageView);

        }
    }

    #region GetFileNames

    void  GetImageFileNames ()
    {
        //ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo (Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath + "/Camera");
        if (dir.Exists == true) {
            FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles ();
            foreach (FileInfo file2 in file) {
                if (file2.Extension == ".jpg" || file2.Extension == ".jpeg" || file2.Extension == ".gif" ||
                    file2.Extension == ".png") {

                    URIs.Add (file2.ToString ());
                }
            }
    //      ImageView ImageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
    //      ImageView.SetImageURI (URIs [1]);
            //  
        } else {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Can not read files from camera folder or no files in camera folder", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

The Adapter

```
public class PicAdapter: BaseAdapter<ImageView>
{   Context context;
    List<ImageView> IMGs;
    public PicAdapter (Context c,List<ImageView> imgs)
    {
        this.context = c;
        this.IMGs = imgs;

    }


    #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter
    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View tile = convertView;

        if (tile == null)
        {
            tile = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.SinglePicTile,null,false);

        }
        ImageView picture = tile.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.PicTile); // here you are making each grid view tiles
        picture = IMGs [position];
        return picture;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get {return IMGs.Count;}
    }
    #endregion

    #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter
    public override ImageView this [int index] {
        get {
            return IMGs [index];
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The Xaml, Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView">
    <GridView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The adapter template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/PicTile"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating `ImageView` instances and handing them over to your `Adapter`. Instead you should just hand it the list of strings and let it handle the initialization. Otherwise you will quickly run out of memory.

So change your `Adapter` to:

```
public class PicAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    private List<string> _imageUrls = new List<string>();

    public void AddImage(string uri)
    {
        _imageUrls.Add(uri);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in `GetView` you would instantiate the view, or reuse one from a previous cell and set the URI, contained in one of the strings you passed the `Adapter`.

Your problem basically lies in this line:

```
picture = IMGs [position];
```

This piece of code does not magically add the `ImageView` to the layout, you need to manipulate the `ImageView` you get from `FindViewById`:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = convertView;

    if (view == null)
        view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.SinglePicTile, parent, false);

    var picture = tile.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.PicTile);
    picture.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(_imageUrls[position]));
    return picture;
}
```

So basically drop the `MakeImageViews()` method, as that is something the `Adapter` should handle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cheesebaron ,i understand your answer. I'm confident it will work,but i apologize because i can not test it now,my xamarin license expired, i will buy a new one on Friday. And will run this then. Thanks again very much. Thanks !